# passing a value from servlet to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I want to pass a java variable to javascript function.this is my coding:
in script:

```
function rolelist(id) {
  if($('#'+id).hasClass('selected'))
  {
    alert(id);
    $('#'+id).removeClass('selected');  
    array.pop(id);
  }
  else
  {
    alert(id);
    $('#'+id).addClass('selected');
    array.push(id);
  }
}
```

In servlet
`pw.println("<a href='javascript:void(0);' id="+s+" class='availalbe_roles' onclick=rolelist(\'"+s+"\')>"+s+"</a><br>");`

`s` is string value. When I click the string it will call the function `rolelist`. For example if `s="initiator"`, when I click initiator it will call the `rolelist` function. If `s="production manager"`,when i click production manager it will not call the function. i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Your id and rolelist function are not quoted

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `'` for function on onclick.. try this

```
pw.println("<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='"+s+"' class='availalbe_roles' onclick='rolelist(\""+s+"\");'>"+s+"</a><br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use method String.format that easy to used

```
pw.println(String.format("<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"%s\" class='availalbe_roles' onclick='rolelist(\"%s\");'>%s</a><br>", s, s, s));
```